# Allow click to act on two overlapping elements simultaneously

Tags: html, angularjs, click, overlapping

I have an iframe in which the page called is all within an `<a>` tag. When I click, it works. What is challenging is that the iframe is overlapping a button and now I cannot click the button. I want that the click would act upon both at the same time. The button is also enclosed in `<a>` tag.

Is there a possible way? I am working with Angular but I guess that should not matter.

So I have

```
<button (click)= "loadData(6)" style = "position:absolute; top:42%; left:46.5%;">Start</button>

<iframe src = "abc.html" class = "pos"></iframe>
```

the iframe completely covers the button.
abc.html has code:

```
<a name = "subE" id = "subE" href="/button/<two>" class="button" style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
</a>
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Comment: I have made all necessary changes